# How Do I Download the Latest Version of PyQt5 Tools?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyqt5

I want to download PyQt5 tools. I wrote the code from the pypi site, but it requests a version from me. He didn't accept what I wrote. I want to download the latest version, how can I do?

```
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5-tools (from versions: none)
```

Comment: what is your OS and python version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the version, for example for version 5.11 write the following command
`pip install pyqt5-tools~=5.11`

Comment: if you still have issues look in to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64542291)